# Promoting certain domains in different countries

Tags: seo, domains, country-specific

*We have two domains:*

- `example.net`
- `example.co.uk`

The `.com` is unavailable. Most of our customer base is UK based, so the `.co.uk` works well for us - we have our marketing site at `example.co.uk`.

We'd now like to target other countries, specifically the USA for starters. So we point the .net at the same marketing site `example.net`. We also use that `.net` domain in USA-specific AdWords campaigns.

But - for natural search, the `.co.uk` is coming out trumps. Is there anything I can do to ensure that users in the USA will mostly see the .net links if they search for things related to our app?

Answer (score -1):

I understand your issue, I will try to give you useful suggestion.

1. Add ahref Lang Tag "en-us" so that Search Engine will think it as US Language website and give Preferences to .net website. set the international Targeting in your Google Webmaster Tool
2. Register your .net website in US Local Business Listing websites.
3. Submit your .net website to the Directories.

Follow these steps and concentrate on getting Traffic to .net website from the all sources of Medium from US Visitor then automatically Google will crawl and give the .net website in search result